# Whats the difference between file downloads on Firefox vs Chrome & Safar?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, firefox, gzip, large-files

I am working on debugging an issue with large file downloads.
My web application will call an API that will download a zip file to the user.

This works fine with 1-5MB files, but some files are about 1GB large, and those will **always** fail on Google Chrome & Safari, but not on Firefox.

The files are stored in an IIS Web Server, a NodeJS application will zip it up and return it to a web application.

When using the inspection tool, the endpoints show a success and the browsers will begin downloading, but once downloading is complete, the browser crashes with no warning besides:
"Error code: STATUS_BREAKPOINT"

Has anybody experienced anything like this before?